# How do I get the latest balance of a token in my wallet after a transaction in ethers?

Tags: metamask, react, ethers.js

I'm very new to developing dApps with Ethers JS and recently created a uniswap clone. But I would like to ask if there is any way to update the balance after a transaction is successfully transferred? Is there an event listener for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I'll show you in the code with comments just by front-end and you don't need to have back-end.

```
//First you require ethers.js
const {ethers} = require('ethers');

//Declare variables (Instead of ABI you can use its interface)
let provider;
let signer;
let signerAddress;
let signerBalance;

let contract;
const contractABI = {ABI_OF_CONTRACT_YOU_WANT_TO_LISTEN_TO}
const contractAddress = ADDRESS_OF_CONTRACT_YOU_WANT_TO_LISTEN_TO;

//Then you need the costumer or user to connects its wallet (metamask)
async () =>{
  await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });

  //Now you need its provider
  provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
  
  //To get signer and its address use function below:
  signer = provider.getSigner();
  signerAddress = await signer.getAddress();

  //Now defining contract you want to listen to.
  contract = await new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);
  
  //Now define listener! (mostly if it sends some token, it triggers Transfer event)
  contract.on("Transfer", (from, to, amount, event) => {
        if (from == signerAddress && to == ADDRESS_OF_CONTRACT_YOU_WANT_SIGNER_TO_SEND_TOKENS_OR_DO_SOMETHING){
            signerBalance = await contract.balanceOf(signerAddress);
            //Now do whatever you want with balance here
        }
    });
  

}
```

Comment: is this only for token related transactions ? What about updating ether balance ?

Comment: To be honest I did not find anything like this for ETH change, so I guess you have to set an interval for its tracking

Comment: I saw an example where you listen for the latest block on your provider, and update it inside. Basically on every new block, get the balance.